# Crosswalk and cordova integration

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime

In my Cordova app how can I test if Crosswalk (https://crosswalk-project.org/) is correctly integrate?
And how to use it to display a web page?

Answer (score 3):

I had difficulty working with the crosswalk cordova examples provided by intel.

Joe Bowser, Android platform lead on Cordova, did a proof of concept, and keeps it here: https://github.com/infil00p/cordova-android/tree/pluggable_webview

Follow his readme to get up and running with crosswalk and cordova in no time.

To ensure that you are actually in the XWalk environment, you can use `navigator.userAgent`

a log of `navigator.userAgent` in Chrome yields:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
```

checking navigator.UserAgent in the xwalk environment should have `Mobile Crosswalk/5.34.104.2` in the resulting string

**edit** formatting

Comment: once crosswalk is integrated will super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); do the trick or do we have to use some other method to use crosswalk's webview

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do code changes to confirm, you can always use Google Chrome and do remote debugging

```
chrome://inspect
```

Ensure your app is running on your device and it's connected to your development machine. Once running, go to the Console tab and you can paste the following:

```
navigator.userAgent
```

This will output something like

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; GT-N7100 Build/LMY47V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.91 Mobile Crosswalk/11.40.277.7 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

You can see Crosswalk in the outputted text.